# Getting averages from data where users have multiple entries on different days

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the average number of people contacted per day for each volunteer and as a team. Each volunteer has a unique volunteer number, and makes multiple contacts in a day. The data is logged in the database with the following columns: volunteer, contacts (listed by the date and time that they made contact), and each contact has a contact ID in a field with some kind of key icon to the left of the name of the field.

I'm trying to get my group's average, and the average for each individual volunteer. I later want to take these averages, and compare them to another area manager's data using joins, as all of our information is on the same database. I have no SQL exp., so I'm running into a wall.

Comment: Questions such as these are much clearer and more readily answerable with examples. Both of the data you start with and the results you'd expect from that example data. I strongly recommend reading this... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You should show the tables you have, the columns in the tables, and you might want to mention what your database is because you can get different answers depending on the RDBMS. Also, as was pointed out, sample data is highly useful for people to supply you with a meaningful answer.